# Altium AutoRouter problems with mixing power signals

Tags: altium, autorouter

I'm using Altium for my board layouts, and for the most part, I hand rout the boards. I'm currently working on a particularly dense board, so I decided to use the autorouter after hand routing about 40% of the board. I had already routed all the power and ground connections, and after setting up the rules and running the autorouter, I found MANY places where the autorouter connected my power and ground plans! How is this possible? It placed(see picture) a power via over a ground via and connected them, after I had already routed power and ground to their own respective vias! Any ideas? I know autorouters are somewhat unreliable, but this is ridiculous..

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bws5pmYyaBJSTUhIeUxSR3JoS1U

Thanks all!

Comment: "Somewhat unreliable" is an understatement! Autorouters are generally more trouble than they're worth and rarely solve any problems. I know dense boards can be daunting (I've done my fair share) but 100% hand routing is the way to go if you want things done right.

Comment: Thanks @DerStrom8 - I think I'm going to have to go back to that method... after I clean this board up... 8 layers... yuck...

Comment: Best of luck to you. You're just going to "Undo" the autoroute, right? You're not going to go back and fix it all by hand...?

Comment: @DerStrom8 - it is done... by hand - days later... thanks lol